# Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors of a non-square data set

Tags: r, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I have just calculated my covariance matrix and in a question I am asked to calculate the first two eigenvalues/eigenvectors of the covariance matrix, but the matrix isn't square.
So, I am just unclear what values to use to calculate these values. Here is a picture of the data to make things easier to understand:

[image]

Comment: That looks square to me.

Comment: on my screen it's about 3 cm long and 15 cm wide :-)

Comment: yep I figured it out there :) was just using the whole data set like an idiot instead of using ev<-eigven(cov(Data)) !

Answer (score 1):

Even if the data is non-square the covariance matrix will still be square. For example, using the builtin `anscombe` data frame:

```
dim(anscombe)
## [1] 11  8

dim(cov(anscombe))
## [1] 8 8
```